# Vertical align text in CSS doesn't work

Tags: css, text, alignment

[image]

I want to vertical align the text 'SITE NAME' in the green space.
It's a H1-text inside a div. The green background is the background of the text and the yellow background is the background of the div with a padding of 5px. I can't solve how to vertical-align the text. I already tried this.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: And you want vertically center the text inside the green background right?

Comment: Yes, so I thought I make the height 100%

Comment: Does your green container has a fixed height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
h1 {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px; // height of your h1
}
```

you can safely lose the

```
vertical-align: middle; 
height: 100%;
```

properties.

[Here](http://codepen.io/fredrocha/pen/gmPRLX) is a codepen.

Also, refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) for a lengthier conversation. As noted there, this solution is good **for one line of text only**.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the below link. I tried a little in w3schools

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_line-height